# Mysql - Merge multiple columns into one while preserving each value

Tags: mysql, sql, merge, multiple-columns

Is there a simple way in Mysql to convert a multi-column resultset into a single-column resultset where each row in the single column contains a single value from each cell in the multi-column resultset?

For instance, say I have a table like:

```
    id    |   fk1   |   fk2   |   fk3   
    1          2         3         4
    5          6         7         8
```

Ideally I'd like to be able to run a query along the lines of:

```
SELECT <some_function>(fk1, fk2, fk3) AS value FROM myTable;
```

...and then get an output like:

```
  value  
    2
    3
    4
    6
    7
    8
```

Is there a straightforward way of doing so, or is the only real option to walk the multi-column resultset in code and extract the values into the format that I want?

The end goal is to be able to use the first query as a subquery in a context where the input can only be a single column of values, like:

```
SELECT * FROM myOtherTable WHERE id IN 
    (SELECT <some_function>(fk1, fk2, fk3) AS value FROM myTable);
```

Thus a pure SQL solution is preferable, if one exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `union all`:

```
select fk1 from mytable union all
select fk2 from mytable union all
select fk3 from mytable;
```

There are other methods, but this is simplest.

For your particular query, you can use `exists` and `or` or `in`:

```
SELECT mo.*
FROM myOtherTable mo
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM MyTable m
              WHERE mo.id IN (m.fk1, m.fk2, m.fk3)
             );
```

EDIT:

For performance, but an index on each `fk` column and use multiple conditions in the `where`:

```
SELECT mo.*
FROM myOtherTable mo
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable m WHERE mo.id = m.fk1) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable m WHERE mo.id = m.fk2) OR
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM MyTable m WHERE mo.id = m.fk3);
```

This will do index lookups, which should be much faster than the original form.

Comment: Thanks, the `where exists` method works (haven't tried the `union all` as the query on `myTable` actually has its own subquery which I don't want to repeat once for each field), but takes significantly longer than just querying for and iterating the multi-column resultset.  Any ideas on things to try to speed it up?

Comment: @aroth . . . Speeding it up is an entirely different matter.  For that, I would suggest normalizing the data structure so you have only one `fk` per row.

Comment: I was afraid of that.  Unfortunately there's quite a bit of legacy code in many different places that's built around the separate fields.  The query is quite fast if I just select into multiple columns, so I guess I'll just do that and handle the rest programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Consider you table name tab1.

Now you can do query like

```
select fk1 from (
   (select fk1 from tab1) 
      union all 
   (select fk2 from tab1)) as rt 
      group by fk1;
```

This will combine your two column in to one. Contains will appear one after another.